# Why does the Command prompt screen open 2-3 times before Android emulator starts?

Tags: android, android-emulator

When the Android emulator is launched in Windows XP/Windows 7), the command prompt opens 2-3 times. So why does that open?

Anyone know of a reason for this?

Comment: Some things are just easier to do using existing command line tools, rather than try to piece together how to do it with API calls.

Comment: Hello sir please open this link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6077/room-for-android-and-kalpen .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you launches the emulator, by default it executes batch file for launching the emulator file. so because of running of these batch files , you can see the command prompt opened & closed.

Comment: what? any description can you give about batch files? I see java jni and set up file for java getting called for avd..avd config files are called..

Comment: those file are called by batch execute of Batch Files @Frankenstein

Comment: I want to know which batch files are called..cause I am searching form morning and till now On net i can't find any clues..

Comment: I am searching for this ans since Kalpesh asked me personally..and I can't find any thing about what actually `emulator -avd name` command performs..they just say start emulator but how? nowhere defined

Comment: # need to use "java.ext.dirs" because "-jar" causes classpath to be ignored
exec "$java_cmd" \
    -Xmx256M $os_opts $java_debug \
    -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="$progdir" \
    -classpath "$jarpath:$swtpath/swt.jar" \
    com.android.sdkmanager.Main "$@"